# Is there a way to pass something more advanced like a method or a comparison to a function?

Tags: javascript, function, applescript

So I was trying to remake some `Array.prototype` functions from Javascript in Applescript. While trying to do that I noticed, that many Javascript functions use something that I think is called an arrow function.

Here is a little recap from what I understand of it:

Arrow functions are built up like this (shown by the `Array.prototype.filter()`-method):

```js
words.filter(word => word.length > 6);
 ^^^    ^^^  ^^^  ^^      ^^^
  1      2    3   4        5
```

<sup>Example taken from [mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).</sup>

1. This specifies the array/list targeted. Easy to implement in Applescript.
2. This specifies the built-in function used. I have no idea how to get this to work because I do not know how to implement steps 3, 4 and 5.
3. This assigns the value that is "assigned" to each item in the list. This could be done statically with something like `repeat with word in words ...` (except for the fact that those words are reserved.), but I do not know of a way to do this dynamically.
4. This is the sign that "points" the compiler to tell it what should happen. I do not think that this is necessary to implement.
5. This is (in this case) a comparison, whether a given word has a higher character count of 6. This decides if the item should stay in or not. This could be recreated using `if count of characters of word > 6 then set end of someNewListWeCreatedOutsideThisLoop to word`.

These arrow functions can also, instead of comparisons, have functions instead like `forEach()`:

```js
array1.forEach(element => console.log(element));
```

<sup>Example taken from [mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).</sup>

Here is what I've tried:

```applescript
on myFunc(fn)
  fn
end
myFunc(log "Hello World")
```

This logs "Hello World" and afterwards throws an error about how not enough parameters were passed.

Here is a bit of a hacky workaround using the command line:

```osascript
set theWords to {"These", "are", "Words."}

forEach(theWords, "theWord => display dialog theWord")

on forEach(theArray, arrowFunction)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to " => "
    set arrowFunction to text items of arrowFunction
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to " "
    return (do shell script "osascript -e 'repeat with " & item 1 of arrowFunction & " in (every word of \"" & (theArray as string) & "\")' -e '" & item 2 of arrowFunction & "' -e 'end repeat'")
end forEach
```

This method works, but it has a tiring syntax, performance speed is slow and I am almost sure that I have overlooked some stylish Applescript method.

Comment: AppleScript itself it is a fairly minimal language, and does not have features such as filter functions or the ability to pass blocks.  You would need to create your own handler(s), using features that the AppleScript language _does_ have, to do the equivalent of a specific function.

Comment: Instead of trying to implement features from JavaScript in AppleScript, why not just use JavaScript?  It has a _lot_ more features (well, just about everything does), and as a bonus can also be used in the Script Editor.

Comment: @red_menace I like JavaScript and I use it regularly, but I haven't gotten into JXA since the documentation isn't as good and I just love Applescript.

Comment: @red_menace: JXA is a dead product. Its Apple event support is crippled, there is no documentation or support worth a damn, and it has zero integration with the rest of the JavaScript (Node) ecosystem. JXA failed so hard, Apple disbanded the Mac Automation team and fired the PM responsible. AppleScript is not a good language, but it’s the only nominally supported option that works right. (For those who like to live dangerously, python appscript and SwiftAutomation still work, but I don’t provide support for either. NodeAutomation is broken due to bitrot in the 3rd-party NodObjC module.)

Comment: For benefit of those less familiar with JS, `word => word.length > 6` is just syntactic sugar for `function (word) {return word.length > 6}`, which is the traditional JS syntax for anonymous (i.e. unnamed) functions. It is more concise, but the meaning is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap a handler containing your custom behavior in a script object. You can then pass the script object as a parameter to another handler and call it there.

```
script Foo
    to doStuff(a, b)
        return a + b
    end doStuff
end script

to bar(obj)
   obj's doStuff(1, 2)
end bar

bar(Foo) 
--> 3
```

ETA: Filtering a list in JavaScript:

```
[1, 4, 6, 2].filter(function (n) {return n < 3})
// [ 1, 2 ]
```

Filtering a list in AppleScript (using the [List](https://github.com/hhas/applescript-stdlib) library):

```
use script "List"

script FilterObj
    to filterItem(n)
        return n < 3
    end filterItem
end script

filter list {1, 4, 6, 2} using FilterObj
--> {1, 2}
```

The AppleScript is more verbose, but they are functionally equivalent.

Comment: How would that help in filtering a list for certain items or calling a method for each item in a list?

Comment: Examples can be [found here](https://github.com/hhas/applescript-stdlib), e.g. `search text`, `filter list`, `sort list` commands.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me towards that. I didn't know such a thing existed.

Comment: It would be interesting to see how you would implement this particular list filtering task. Because I don't know much about the intricacies of JavaScript.