# AppleScript pass expression into function to be re-evaluated repeatedly? (or: AppleScript handler with callback?)

Tags: callback, applescript

I think the correct description for what I'm trying to do is be able to pass an expression or function/handler into another handler as a parameter/argument.  Some code to be evaluated inside the receiving handler. Similar to Javascript callbacks, I think.

For example, something like this:

```
on waitFor(theConditionExpression)
    timeout_start(5) -- start a 5 second timer
    repeat until (theConditionExpression or timeout_isExpired())
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    return theConditionExpression
end waitFor
```

- `theConditionExpression` should be some expression or function that evaluates to a boolean result.
- not really relevant to the question, but just FYI, `timeout_start(…)` and `timeout_isExpired()` are two simple handlers I've written that do exactly what they say. (`…start()` doesn't return anything, `…isExpired()` returns a boolean).

Of course, typically if I pass in some boolean expression, it will evaluate that expression once, at the time I pass it in.  But I want it to evaluate it every time it's referenced in the code inside the handler.

Some languages (not sure about AS) have some kind of eval() function that you can pass it some code as a string and it will execute that string as code. Theoretically that could solve this, but: (a) I don't know if AS has anything like that, but even if it does, (b) it's not desired for various reasons (performance, injection risks, etc.)

So I'm thinking something more like eg. JavaScript's ability to pass in a function (named or anonymous) as function parameter/argument that can be re-evaluated every iteration in a loop, etc. (eg. like the `compareFn` argument in JS's Array.sort(compareFn)).

Can AS do anything like this, and if so how?

Thanks!

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69608073/is-there-a-way-to-pass-something-more-advanced-like-a-method-or-a-comparison help?

Comment: It would be helpful if you supplied actual code rather than a _"let's imagine we have something like..."_.  I understand you can't achieve fully what you aim to do just yet, but you could provide samples from your script that call `waitFor`, which shows what's being being passed into `conditionExpression`.  Although you said not relevant, you could consider showing the two timing-related handlers, because it might be relevant to some different way of thinking about or approaching the problem.

Comment: @CJK Thanks for the suggestions. I agree my post smacks of an XY problem, but it really is about a whole range of situations where, in JS, I would solve it with a function as an argument (eg. like JS itself's `Array.sort(compareFn)`.  My question is definitively about the generic question of "Can AS do the same thing, one way or another?" for a wide range of situations.  My code above is just one example...

Comment: ...If the answer is "No, AS doesn't have anything like that" then that's ok -- I'll then look at each situation where I'd have used that, and figure out how to solve it some other way, appropriate to the situation, case by case.  But before I go there, I was looking for the general answer either way.  It seems @red_menace's answer might actually cover it, actually although I'm still working on that, before I'm sure.

Comment: @red_menace Thanks for the tip.  It looks like that might be the answer, although Iv'e been swamped the last few days and haven't had a chance to look more deeply than just cursory at the moment.  I'll investigate further and let you know.  Thanks!

Comment: OK, that's a good answer/justification in response to my question/accusation, actually, so thanks for articulating your position.  The answer is probably closer to _"kind of"_, depending on specific use-cases: what you're describing are _first-class functions_ in JS, which are functions that can be passed around by the script like data, without losing track of the scope in which they operate. AppleScript handlers aren't functions at all, just data objects that are not self-aware. But Script Objects can be used to emulate first-class behaviour similar to a JS anonymous function.

Comment: The other option having seen your comment under Ted's answer about the UI scripting case is to define a handler to which you would pass `a reference to...` the UI element you're waiting upon. You're right that this can't really be done in an asynchronous fashion, which would be lovely, but by passing the UI element by reference, you'd be able to have a re-usable handler that can check for existence and either return a `true`/`false`/timeout result, or return a reference to UI elements that evaluate successfully amongst a collection of UI elements that it was passed.

Comment: I *might* be wrong in saying this, but out of the two potential approaches, the Script Object might not be appropriate in the specific case of UI scripting, as I vaguely recall limitations relating to sending an object reference from one scope to be operated on by a handler defined inside a different scope, which couldn't cope if there was any recursively-nested calls made upon a non-dereferenced object. Not an issue if just a simple call-and-response operation, but, say, scouring a hierarchy may need the Ui-reference-as-parameter approach.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest (*pro forma*) that an AppleScript application with an `on idle` handler is generally a better solution for wait conditions than a repeat/delay loop. It's more efficient for the system, and doesn't freeze up the script. But that would involve reconceptualizing your script, and I'm not certain it would work in this case, given the way you formed the problem.

There's an old but good site called [AppleScript Power Handlers](http://www.apeth.net/matt/unm/asph.html) that shows a bunch of nifty-neato tricks for sophisticated use of AppleScript handlers: passing handlers as values or parameters; creating Script Objects within handlers; making closures and constructors. I'm pretty sure the answer to your request is in there. aLikely you'll want to set up a bunch of handlers that serve as condition expressions, then pass them as parameters to the evaluating handler. Or maybe you'll want to set up a script object containing the condition handlers and call it as needed?

At any rate, see what you can do with it, and ask more specific questions if you run into problems.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Yes, in some situations, `on idle` is great. In the particular case relating to my example, I'm in the middle of some synchronous UI scripting, & I'm waiting for a particular UI element to exist before I try to click on it.  So I'm not sure `on idle` is appropriate in that case...? Feel free to suggest otherwise, & how, if I'm wrong. For now, the steps within the above handler, & the conditions in each case, are hard-coded into what would otherwise call the above handler. In this case I'm looking for a way to abstract that out and make it more generic…

Comment: …That said, it's just one example of the bigger question. See my comment above to CJK about the more generic point of the question --  "Can AS do the same thing as JS's 'functions as arguments' feature, one way or another, for usage in AS in all the situations where it's useful and appropriate in JS?"  red_menace's comment looks like one solution.  There seems to be some solutions in that Power Handlers link also.  I'll investigate further and report back.    Thanks!